# Stateful component or stateful service in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I am new with Angular 2 and I wanted to know if there is any advantage of having stateful components over stateful services. Which one is the standard approach and is there any advantage of using one over the other. I tried to google the answer for this but its not really covered anywhere. I would really appreciate it if someone can clear this up for me. Thanks.